# VB.Net Change HighLight Color on ListBox

Tags: vb.net

I have code here that changes the color of the highlight of a listbox. But when the listbox is empty it gives an error **InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index**
and the form will go into a not responding state.

```
    Private Sub BranchListBox_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles BranchListBox.DrawItem
        Dim mybrush As New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 177, 89))
        mybrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 177, 89)


            Try
                e.DrawBackground()
                If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(mybrush, e.Bounds)
                End If
                Using b As New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(BranchListBox.GetItemText(BranchListBox.Items(e.Index)), e.Font, b, e.Bounds)
                End Using
                e.DrawFocusRectangle()
            Catch ex As Exception

                 ColorAppend(LogsBox, Color.Red, TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss") & SystemLog & ex.Message & Environment.NewLine)
                LogsBox.ScrollToCaret()
            End Try

    End Sub
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid this event in case there is no `ListBox.Item`:

```
Private Sub BranchListBox_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles BranchListBox.DrawItem

    'exit this event in case there is not valid index.
    If e.Index = -1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim mybrush As New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 177, 89))
    mybrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 177, 89)

    Try
        e.DrawBackground()

        If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(mybrush, e.Bounds)
        End If

        Using b As New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(BranchListBox.GetItemText(BranchListBox.Items(e.Index)), e.Font, b, e.Bounds)
        End Using

        e.DrawFocusRectangle()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ColorAppend(LogsBox, Color.Red, TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss") & SystemLog & ex.Message & Environment.NewLine)
        LogsBox.ScrollToCaret()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You SO SO MUCH <3 <3 <3